# How do I plug in a electrospace sg2 compressor to my amp

Tags: electronics

I have recently bought a used electrospace sg2 compressor for my guitar but I don’t know how to plug it in. There are 3 spots to plug things in on in the back. 1 of them look like what you’d plug a microphone cable to, 2 are the kinda opposite with space only for the 3 pin like things and a big circle on the outside, and the other 1 is a regular jack output. I’m not sure if I have to buy a new cord or not, I have tons of regular jack chords but no microphone cables or anything like that.

Comment: This is rack-mounted gear. Normally between you and it would be a direct box or amp, so yes, it would be xlr cables that would go in and out. I'm also not too sure about the idea of going *to* an amp out of this...

Comment: @Alex You will need to provide more information, you describe XLR inputs and outputs (inputs to the amp will have space to 'accept' the 3 XLR pins, these are XLR female sockets. Outputs from the amp will have the 3 XLR pins visible, these are XLR male sockets) The important thing is what these sockets are labelled as. Often with guitar effects you go directly into them and then into the amp, this will not work that well/at-all here as the compressor is not designed to accept a guitar signal directly. If your amp has an fx loop you might be in business.

Comment: Bear in mind compressors are not usually put in a guitars fx loop, nothing technically wrong with it but you might not get the sound you are looking for and it will require adjusting every time you adjust your amp.

Comment: Maybe a good idea for a separate question would be to elaborate on why you are planning to add this to your rig and what result you're hoping for, and whether this is the best way.